# Display geojson from string

Tags: android, maps, geojson

In my app I receive data from API. Part of my object is geometry that I can display as geojson. String looks like this :

```
 {"type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [[[22.22, 22.22], [22.22, 22.22], [22.22,22.22 ], ... , ]]}
```

How can I convert it to geojson (polygon) and display it on map in he easiest way , please ?

Comment: What is the exact problem? Parsing a (Geo)JSON object from the string or showing a GeoJSON polygon on a map or both?

Comment: Problem is that this String is already geojson. Can I just display it on map, or I need to convert it to POJO class and create polygons ?

Comment: Depends on the map. Looks like [a Google Map has support](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/geojson) and also an OSMDROID map [can display GeoJSON with the bonus pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790500/parse-and-view-geojson-with-osmbonuspack). I actually haven't tried either one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this kind of **POJO class** for your response to parse:

```
package com.foo;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Foo {

    @SerializedName("type")
    @Expose
    private String type;

    @SerializedName("coordinates")
    @Expose
    private List<List<List<Double>>> coordinates = null;

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public List<List<List<Double>>> getCoordinates() {
        return coordinates;
    }

    public void setCoordinates(List<List<List<Double>>> coordinates) {
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
    }

}
```

Now, use this class to display your routes on map.

Comment: Yes I know but I guess , I can do it quicker ... ;)

Comment: Okay, that means i didn't get what you wanted as solutions ;p, please update the OP for your exact requirements, i'll look into it

Answer (score 0):

Your json is as below

```
{
"type": "Polygon",
"coordinates": [
    [22.22, 22.22],
    [22.22, 22.22],
    [22.22, 22.22]
]
```

}

you can use [this](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) link to convert any type of json to pojo class.