# Custom OSM android studio integration

Tags: java, android, openstreetmap

i want to make an Android Studio (Java) app with OpenStreetMap and custom geoJson data. I'm not able to create the custom map with the layers i want; I tryed to use uMap or similar but using that i can't integrate it in my Android Studio Java app. Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: Take a look at [https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid). It allows adding custom data as layers. There's also [https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack) that adds more features and allows using GeoJSON directly: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790500/parse-and-view-geojson-with-osmbonuspack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790500/parse-and-view-geojson-with-osmbonuspack)